# New Order Email Details Missing // Woocommerce / Woocommerce Bookings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have the administration of the tour agency website with booking functionality built in Wordpress, Woocommerce and Woocommerce Bookings. For one product at the new order email not mentioned the booking details like how many persons will join to the tour. I am facing this issue only for one product, all the others are ok. I am attaching also some screenshots that many help you.

[Screenshot with missing details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vUde.png)
[Screenshot with correct details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znCZI.png)

It would be great if you can help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.